# Tireder (comparative form)

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, past-participles, inflectional-morphology

According to the CambridgeGEL, page 1583,

> Participial adjectives take only analytic comparative forms (A
> marginal exception is **tired**)

What are the reasons leading to this exception?

Comment: Idioms are much like memes. If someone says something that has a good ring to it, others will copy. I would use it as in, "I feel tireder than I have for a long time."

Comment: @chaslyfromUK that's definitely NOT an idiom though

Comment: Which definition of idiom are you using?